# When exactly is compileComponents needed?

Tags: angular, jestjs, testbed

I am migrating my component unit tests with only jest to UI tests using Testbed and jest (Before I had just unit test with `component = new MyCompontent()`).

I am using Angular 11.

There is one thing I do not understand about `compileComponents`. In the docs it says ["You can ignore this section if you only run tests with the CLI ng test command because the CLI compiles the application before running the tests."](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#calling-compilecomponents)

I am not calling `ng test` but `jest --watch` but my tests work both with and without `compileComponents` ( by work I mean they assert correctly my view).

Also there is a ["You must call this method if any of the testing module components have a templateUrl or styleUrls because fetching component template and style files is necessarily asynchronous"](https://angular.io/guide/testing-utility-apis#testbed-class-summary)

My component is using both `templateUrl` and `styleUrls`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-example',
  templateUrl: './my-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-example.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyExampleComponent {}
```

So what I am missing? I want to be sure that my test will not break if I eventually set a CI or similar.

or should I always call `compileComponents` ? I am under the impression it will be not so efficent to do this if not needed.

So, when exactly does `compileComponents` is needed ?

Edit:

This is my jest config

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ionic|@saninn|@ngrx|@capacitor-community|@capacitor)'],
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', ...ignoredFiles],
  coverageReporters: process.env.CI ? ['text'] : ['lcov'],
  // coverageReporters: ['lcov'],
  // coverageReporters: ['text'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', ...ignoredFiles],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [...ignoredFiles],
  collectCoverage: false,
  notify: true,
  // notifyMode: 'failure',
  coverageDirectory: './coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts', '!**/*.module.ts', '!**/*.enum.ts'],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', 'package.json', ...ignoredFiles],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/src/tsconfig.spec.json',
      diagnostics: {
        ignoreCodes: [
          6138, // declared but never read
          6133, // declared but never used,
          2322 // object should just have known keys
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you please tell us more about your configuration? Are you using Angular CLI? How did you configure jest?

Comment: Hi @yurzui I had added my jest.config.js file to the post. Thanks!

Comment: You're using `jest-preset-angular` that includes resource transformer https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/blob/master/src/transformers/replace-resources.ts It does the same what Angular CLI does when compiles application

Comment: I see. Thanks! Can you maybe put this on an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you don't see any difference between running `ng test` and `jest` command because your jest configuration uses `jest-preset-angular` that involves its own Angular replace resource transformer https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/blob/master/src/transformers/replace-resources.ts

```
 * Given the input
 * @Component({
 *   selector: 'foo',
 *   templateUrl: './foo.component.html`,
 *   styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss'],
 *   styles: [`h1 { font-size: 16px }`],
 * })
 *
 * Produced the output for `CommonJS`
 * @Component({
 *   selector: 'foo',
 *   templateUrl: require('./foo.component.html'),
 *   styles: [],
 * })
```

That is similar that Angular CLI does https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/replace_resources.ts

See also:

- **[Do you know how Angular transforms your code?](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/do-you-know-how-angular-transforms-your-code-7943b9d32829)**